# Server sticker says "WindowsServer®08 Std 1-4cpu" which version of Windows Server is this?

Tags: windows-server

The presence of 08 initally suggests Server 2008 but I doubt that's correct.  The server is relatively old and it currently has Server 2003 installed on it (not necesarrily the OS that it came installed with)

I'm guessing 2003 but I just wanted to ask to make sure.  As usual in cases like this Google is no help because it just interprets my '08' as '2008' and returns those results, or if I wrap in quote marks I get lots of not-very-easy-to-make-sense-of websites.

Comment: Windows Server 2008 is Windows Vista's Server Edition Software.  Windows Vista was released in Jan 2007 and Windows Server 2008 was released in Feb 2008.  It sounds like whom ever setup the sever "downgraded" the operating system likely for compatability reasons.  Furthermore...The sticky clearly says "Windows Server 2008" unless were talking about a fake sticker and only you can tell us that.

Comment: No,  the sticker says '08'  not '2008'   hence the reason for my being not quite 100% sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the released versions of Windows Server:

- Windows 2000 Server
- Windows Server 2003
- Windows Server 2008
- Windows Server 2008 R2

It's a Windows Server 2008 sticker.

Answer (score 2):

The "Windows Server 2008 Standard Edition" suports up to 4 CPU sockets, so that is most likely what the sticker means.